# Sum values day by day Qlik Sense

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

I have table with 3 important atributes: CT, DATE and OpenClosed. I have combo chart (on X axis is Date {2016-6-12} day by day) with two values: `Count( {< OpenClosed = {'CLOSED'} >}Distinct CT)` and `Count( {< OpenClosed = {'OPEN'} >}Distinct CT)` for open and closed CTs. I need add line chart to this combo chart with sum of counts of Open CTs day by day. For example: 4th December 2200 CTs, 5th December 2310 CTs, 6th December 2250 CTs..... Is it possible, or I must do some special table in Excel in this case? Thanks for your answers ;)

edited:
[image] 
TOTAL OPEN CT is solved by `Count( {< OpenClosed = {'OPEN'} >}Distinct CT)`
It is for all days, but I need line chart day by day to combo chart...

Comment: A screenshot of your chart would help and perhaps an example of how the data is structured.

Comment: Does that chart not already show (red bars) the number of open CT's by day? Are you looking for a running cumulative sum?

Comment: I need have number, which is in big KPI (TOTAL CT...) in the each bar in bar chart for each single day as a line... I have this (not correct) solve yet: rangesum(
below(Count( {< OpenClosed = {'OPEN'} >}Distinct CT),0,Rowno())
)